# Pip List shows strange packages/names

Tags: python, pip

my "pip3 list" shows the following list:

```
-          thon   
-.thon     0.29.10
-thon      0.29.10
-ython     0.29.10
pip        19.0.3 
setuptools 40.8.0 
wheel      0.33.1
```

I think they are connected to a version of Cython previously installed.

If I type

```
pip3 freeze | xargs pip3 uninstall -y
```

The error is the following:

```
Could not parse requirement: -thon
Could not parse requirement: -ython
Could not parse requirement: -.thon
Could not parse requirement: -
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+uninstall+dash

Comment: Find them in your `site-packages/` and remove them manually.